# Create video with identical frames in matlab

Tags: matlab, video, matlab-figure

I am creating a video for a presentation with matlab. The video shows a optimization algorithm moving towards the minimum of a costfunction. I want the last seconds of the video to be a freeze-frame, which means that I use the writevideo function to write a couple of identical frames. However when I play the video with VLC player or with powerpoint the correct length of the video is shown, but the identical frames of the video are "skipped". Is there any way I can stop this?

My Code looks like this:

```
graph = figure('units','pixels','position',[0 0 1920 1080]);
scatter3... %(first frame)

v = VideoWriter('Presentation.avi');
v.Quality = 95;
v.FrameRate = 1;
open(v);

frame = getframe(graph);
writeVideo(v,frame);

for i = 1:10
    plot3... %(changing frames)
    frame = getframe(graph);
    writeVideo(v,frame);
end

for j = 1:5
    %(identical frames)
    frame = getframe(graph);
    writeVideo(v,frame);
end

close(v);
```

Thank you for answering!

Comment: It's not clear if the frames are actually present. Have you tried using Matlab's `VideoReader` to count the number of frames in the file and display them back? Also, you don't need to call `getframe` inside the loop that is creating identical frames  just use the value of `frame` from the previous loop.

Comment: I executed your code (I had to fill the parts you removed), and the code is working fine in my machine. Your claim doesn't make sense. I don't think your player skips identical frames.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that includes the plotting parts (it doesn't have to be your real code, preferably it will be some super simple plotting that still generates the same problem).